# Selecting old/new value from audit table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have an audit table which contains snapshots for whenever there is a change.

```
| property_id | provider_id | datetime_in           | datetime_out          
|-------------|-------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
| 1145        | 120         | 2018-11-01 00:00:00.0 | 2018-11-02 00:00:00.0 |
| 1145        | 180         | 2018-11-02 00:00:00.0 | 2018-11-03 00:00:00.0 |
| 1145        | 120         | 2018-11-03 00:00:00.0 | NULL                  
| 1110        | 150         | 2018-11-01 00:00:00.0 | NULL
```

I want to select all properties who were with provider X at some stage but eventually switched to a new provider. `datetime_out` being `NULL` indicates that the row represents the current status.

My output should look like for provider 120:

```
| property_id | old_provider| new_provider | switched_at          
|-------------|-------------|--------------|---------------------
| 1145        | 120         | 180          | 2018-11-02 00:00:00.0
```

I have tried this so far (based on another SO thread):

```
SELECT 
    a.property_id, 
    a.provider_id as new_provider,
    lag(provider_id) over (partition by property_id order by datetime_in) as previous_value
 FROM schema.mytable a
```

However, this isn't working as intended. What would be the best way to query this audit table?

Comment: What is wrong? At first glance it looks good

Comment: @leftjoin From the result I see, my query includes rows where there was no change i.e. old_provider = new_provider. This could be due to other columns in the table can change without the provider changing. It also isn't limited to X provider as I can't used the aliased columns in the where condition.

Comment: @leftjoin I think my answer below addresses those concerns I replied to you with. Should be all good now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the below does the trick:

```
SELECT 
    b.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.property_id, 
        a.provider_id as new_provider,
        lag(provider_id) over (partition by property_id order by datetime_in) as previous_provider
    FROM schema.mytable a
) b

WHERE b.previous_value IN (XXX)
    AND b.previous_provider != b.new_provider
```